# C#, BindingNavigator, Ugly line at the right end

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingnavigator

How do I get rid of this ugly line?

[image]

Draw a default bindingnavigator on an empty Form and you will see the problem. RenderMode is ManagerRenderMode. I want this render mode so the mouse over colors is correct. However, If I switch to System as rendermode the ugly line disapears, but then  mouse over color/effect gets ugly.

I have been looking around for a solution for some time now, but nothing. Maybe someone here have seen this problem before?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a `BindingNavigator` specific issue, but the `ToolStrip` which `BindingNavigator` inherits.

It's caused by the [`DrawToolStripBorder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriprenderer.drawtoolstripborder(v=vs.110).aspx) method when the  [`ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx) class [`RoundedEdges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer.roundededges(v=vs.110).aspx) property is `true` (the default).

In order to turn it off, I can suggest the following helper method:

```
public static class WindowsFormsExtensions
{
    public static void DisableRoundedEdges(this ToolStripRenderer renderer)
    {
        var professionalRenderer = renderer as ToolStripProfessionalRenderer;
        if (professionalRenderer != null)
            professionalRenderer.RoundedEdges = false;
    }
}
```

Now you can turn it off for the specific control (it's not available at design time, so it has to be at run time inside your form/control constructor or load event):

```
this.bindingNavigator1.Renderer.DisableRoundedEdges();
```

or to disable it globally, add the following in your `Main` method before calling `Application.Run`:

```
ToolStripManager.Renderer.DisableRoundedEdges();
```

Comment: Wonderful!! Looks much better now. I disabled it globally now. 

Thanks a lot!